# Understanding Delegates & Callbacks

Tags: c#, callback, delegates

Using this C# TCP Server example within a Unity project

https://www.codeproject.com/articles/488668/csharp-tcp-server

The notes mention *There are 3 callback events OnConnect, OnDataAvailable and OnError.*
There are 2 callback examples with the following signatures

```
private void tcpServer1_OnDataAvailable(tcpServer.TcpServerConnection connection)
```

Do I need to do anything special or in  addition to enable these callbacks or is ***tcpServer1_OnDataAvailable*** consdiered a reserved handler name that is automatically called?

```
TcpServer tcpServer1 = new TcpServer(); //in constructor (auto added if added as a component)

private void openTcpPort(int port)
{ 
    tcpServer1.Port = port;
    tcpServer1.Open();
}

private void closeTcpPort()
{
    tcpServer1.Close();
}
```

Comment: you will need to register the callback with the events provided in the `TCPServer` type

Comment: Look at msdn.  You can replace the socket class in the code with any class that inherits the socket class like TcpClient and TcpListener : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to register the event handlers delegates to the specific events.

```
TcpServer tcpServer1 = new TcpServer(); 

// register event handler
tcpServer1.OnDataAvailable += tcpServer1_OnDataAvailable;


private void tcpServer1_OnDataAvailable(tcpServer.TcpServerConnection connection)
{
  // do work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks are methods that are called when an event you are interested in occurs.  You do in fact need to set them up, like this:

```
tcpServer1.OnConnect += serverConnection => 
{
   //code to do stuff when a connection happens goes here
}

tcpServer1.OnDataAvailable += serverConnection =>
{
  //code to do stuff when data is available here
}

tcpServer1.OnError += serverConnection => 
{
   //code to do stuff when an error happens here
}
```

You should put this code in the constructor, after the point in time when tcpServer1's variable is instantiated with operator new.